# Get the first char of each word oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, database, string, oracle

I need regex code for get the first letter of each word in the string column then I have to replace others letter with '*'.

Example: `Template Extension for Labeler Transformation`

Result I need: `T**** E***** f** L*** T***`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with two passes of `regexp_replace()`:

```
with t as (select 'Template Extension for Labeler Transformation' v from dual)
select regexp_replace( regexp_replace(v, '(\w)\w', '\1*'), '\*\w', '**') new_v
from t
```

Explanation:

The inner call to `regexp_replace()` matches on sequences of two consecutive word characters and replaces the second one with `*`. For your example string, this produces:

```
T*m*l*t* E*t*n*i*n f*r L*b*l*r T*a*s*o*m*t*o*
```

The the outer `regexp_replace()` matches on a star followed by a word character, and replaces the word character with a star. This results in the expected output:

```
T******* E******** f** L****** T*************
```

**[Step by step demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9161263fe4ec6130831c619d89c6a116)**

Comment: This is very clever.

Comment: Much appreciated @GordonLinoff!

Answer (score 4):

I used initcap() to make the first letters of each word uppercase, then replaced all the lowercases with asterisks.

> ```
> with fb as (
> select initcap('sampiyon fenerbahce') foo from dual)
> select REGEXP_replace(foo,'[a-z]', '*')sd from fb
> ```

result should be seen like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

- `split` CTE splits input string to rows (i.e. *words*)
- `masked` CTE uses `regexp_replace` and masks all characters from the second position
- the final select uses `listagg` to aggregate masked words back into the "original" string

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Template Extension for Labeler Transformation' from dual),
  3  split as
  4    (select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level) val,
  5            level lvl
  6     from test
  7     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
  8    ),
  9  masked as
 10    (select regexp_replace(val, '.', '*', 2) msk,
 11            lvl
 12        From split
 13    )
 14  select listagg(msk, ' ') within group (order by lvl) result
 15  from masked;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T******* E******** f** L****** T*************

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution a procedure PL SQL:

```
create or replace procedure pr_first_letters(p_word in varchar2, p_result out varchar2) as 
l_temp_word varchar2(40) := p_word;
l_space_position number(3);
begin
loop
l_space_position := instr(l_temp_word , ' ');
p_result := concat(p_result,substr(l_temp_word ,1,1));
if l_space_position > 0 then
l_temp_word := substr(l_temp_word,l_space_position + 1, length(l_temp_word));
else
exit;
end if;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a simple way, found it on the [link](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2233588/first-character-in-each-word):

Written by Mr. Frank Kulash check it out

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( INITCAP ('Statement to be PARSED')
           , '[^A-Z]')
AS inits FROM  dual;
```